# add tag base on variable in loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

imagine I have to generate a list of li

```
{map(listItems, (obj,i) => 
    <li key={i}>
      <a target="_blank" href={obj.itemName === 'view_detail' ? `event/${id}` : ''} >
            <i className={obj.icon}></i>
            {obj.name}
      </a>
    </li>
)}
```

this won't work, because even the li is not view_detail, it will still have target blank.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Do you want to disable click event if obj.itemName !== 'view_detail'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As one of solution - change target dynamicly as href

```
<li key={i}>
      <a target={obj.itemName === 'view_detail' ? `_blank` : ''} href={obj.itemName === 'view_detail' ? `event/${id}` : ''} >
            <i className={obj.icon}></i>
            {obj.name}
      </a>
    </li>
```